Failed to resolve 'gwcdfas0csrtxc09.search.windows.net' ([Errno -2] Name or service not known)
I'm running graphrag solution accelerator from Microsoft to build an index, I'm getting an error at step 7. The application is deployed to kubernetes clusters. There is a pod for frontend and backend. I’m running the backend pod to create the index. The permissions are given correctly by the infra team. But somehow I’m stuck with this error,
[INFO] 2024-11-01 04:58:52,085 - Index: testing-index -- Workflow (1/16): create_base_text_units started.
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/numpy/core/fromnumeric.py:59: FutureWarning: 'DataFrame.swapaxes' is deprecated and will be removed in a future version. Please use 'DataFrame.transpose' instead.
  return bound(*args, **kwds)
[INFO] 2024-11-01 04:58:55,377 - Index: testing-index -- Workflow (1/16): create_base_text_units complete.
[INFO] 2024-11-01 04:58:56,901 - Index: testing-index -- Workflow (2/16): create_base_extracted_entities started.
[INFO] 2024-11-01 05:08:42,824 - Index: testing-index -- Workflow (2/16): create_base_extracted_entities complete.
[INFO] 2024-11-01 05:08:44,580 - Index: testing-index -- Workflow (3/16): create_final_covariates started.
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/datashaper/engine/verbs/convert.py:65: FutureWarning: errors='ignore' is deprecated and will raise in a future version. Use to_numeric without passing `errors` and catch exceptions explicitly instead
  column_numeric = cast(pd.Series, pd.to_numeric(column, errors="ignore"))
[INFO] 2024-11-01 05:17:35,607 - Index: testing-index -- Workflow (3/16): create_final_covariates complete.
[INFO] 2024-11-01 05:17:37,188 - Index: testing-index -- Workflow (4/16): create_summarized_entities started.
[INFO] 2024-11-01 05:22:38,155 - Index: testing-index -- Workflow (4/16): create_summarized_entities complete.
[INFO] 2024-11-01 05:22:39,881 - Index: testing-index -- Workflow (5/16): join_text_units_to_covariate_ids started.
[INFO] 2024-11-01 05:22:40,033 - Index: testing-index -- Workflow (5/16): join_text_units_to_covariate_ids complete.
[INFO] 2024-11-01 05:22:41,396 - Index: testing-index -- Workflow (6/16): create_base_entity_graph started.
[INFO] 2024-11-01 05:22:49,056 - Index: testing-index -- Workflow (6/16): create_base_entity_graph complete.
[INFO] 2024-11-01 05:22:50,693 - Index: testing-index -- Workflow (7/16): create_final_entities started.
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/numpy/core/fromnumeric.py:59: FutureWarning: 'DataFrame.swapaxes' is deprecated and will be removed in a future version. Please use 'DataFrame.transpose' instead.
  return bound(*args, **kwds)
Error executing verb "text_embed" in create_final_entities: <urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x7f5147500b50>: Failed to resolve 'gwcdfas0csrtxc09.search.windows.net' ([Errno -2] Name or service not known) 

This is the pipeline_settings.yaml file.
this is the pipeline_settings.yaml, # Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation.
# Licensed under the MIT License.

# this yaml file serves as a configuration template for the graphrag indexing jobs
# some values are hardcoded while others denoted by PLACEHOLDER will be dynamically set
input:
  type: blob
  file_type: text
  file_pattern: .*\.txt$
  storage_account_blob_url: $STORAGE_ACCOUNT_BLOB_URL
  connection_string: $STORAGE_CONNECTION_STRING
  container_name: PLACEHOLDER
  base_dir: .

storage:
  type: blob
  storage_account_blob_url: $STORAGE_ACCOUNT_BLOB_URL
  connection_string: $STORAGE_CONNECTION_STRING
  container_name: PLACEHOLDER
  base_dir: output

reporting:
  type: blob
  storage_account_blob_url: $STORAGE_ACCOUNT_BLOB_URL
  connection_string: $STORAGE_CONNECTION_STRING
  container_name: PLACEHOLDER
  base_dir: logs

cache:
  type: blob
  storage_account_blob_url: $STORAGE_ACCOUNT_BLOB_URL
  connection_string: $STORAGE_CONNECTION_STRING
  container_name: PLACEHOLDER
  base_dir: cache

llm:
  type: azure_openai_chat
  api_base: $GRAPHRAG_API_BASE
  api_version: $GRAPHRAG_API_VERSION
  model: $GRAPHRAG_LLM_MODEL
  deployment_name: $GRAPHRAG_LLM_DEPLOYMENT_NAME
  cognitive_services_endpoint: $GRAPHRAG_COGNITIVE_SERVICES_ENDPOINT
  api_key: $OPENAI_API_KEY 
  model_supports_json: True
  tokens_per_minute: 80000
  requests_per_minute: 480
  thread_count: 50
  concurrent_requests: 25

parallelization:
  stagger: 0.25
  num_threads: 10

async_mode: threaded

embeddings:
  async_mode: threaded
  llm:
    type: azure_openai_embedding
    api_base: $GRAPHRAG_API_BASE
    api_version: $GRAPHRAG_API_VERSION
    batch_size: 16
    model: $GRAPHRAG_EMBEDDING_MODEL
    deployment_name: $GRAPHRAG_EMBEDDING_DEPLOYMENT_NAME
    cognitive_services_endpoint: $GRAPHRAG_COGNITIVE_SERVICES_ENDPOINT
    api_key: $OPENAI_API_KEY 
    tokens_per_minute: 350000
    concurrent_requests: 25
    requests_per_minute: 2100
    thread_count: 50
    max_retries: 50
  parallelization:
    stagger: 0.25
    num_threads: 10
  vector_store:
    type: azure_ai_search
    collection_name: PLACEHOLDER
    title_column: name
    overwrite: True
    url: $AI_SEARCH_URL
    audience: $AI_SEARCH_AUDIENCE
    api_key: $AI_SEARCH_SERVICE_KEY

entity_extraction:
  prompt: PLACEHOLDER

community_reports:
  prompt: PLACEHOLDER

summarize_descriptions:
  prompt: PLACEHOLDER

# claim extraction is disabled by default in the graphrag library so we enable it for the solution accelerator
claim_extraction:
  enabled: True

snapshots:
  graphml: True

Actually the permissions is already given to that ai_search_url.
Should I include some more details to this?
